# Passing external data to an existing React component

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am integrating React components in an existing website. I do not want to build an SPA, but there are certain area where more dynamic elements would be very useful.

To that end, I am using the following pattern:

- define separate components in their own file, e.g. `Login.jsx`
- in `index.jsx`, import all components if a holder div is found for them, e.g. if `<div id="login">` exists, render `<Login >` in it

I am now trying to add some modal dialogs to a couple of pages. The approach that I had is:

- add the following div to all pages: `<div id="modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"></div>`
- create a `Modal` react component which contains the markup required for bootstrap
- wire the react component to the div
- add buttons on specific pages, where needed: `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">`

With this setup I can define the markup only once and display the modal on the pages that need it. The problem that I have is that I need to modal to have different content, based on the page it is in (and not only).

I could store some global data in the `window` object but I find that quite ugly.

What options do I have for passing external data to existing React components? I'm open to other options as well, even if they mean adjusting the way I incorporate React.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm qualified to list all of the possible options, but another one that I'm using is to write the data as json into a `<script id="data">` tag, and then select and parse out that data for use in hydrating react state. For me, it felt cleaner than polluting `window`

Comment: Another option would be make all react code in a single app but use [Portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) to render each component in different elements from the original html files. This way you will be saving code duplication as well (if you make each component totally apart you'll end up with all React library and other modules inside each one, for example)

Comment: @MitchLillie - that is a cool idea ,never thought of it. Can you make it an answer, it definitely needs more visibility :-)

Comment: @Coluccini - thanks for pointing me to portals, I did not know about that. Can you make it your comment an answer, it definitely needs more visibility :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on my comment, I think that the right way to approach your idea (if I got it right) is to make all React code in a single app but use [Portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) to render each component in different elements from the original html files (in fact the example on Portal's link do something similar of what your are wanting to do).

This way you will be saving code duplication as well (if you make each component totally apart you'll end up with all React library and other modules inside each one, for example) and it would be easy to access to to component method from other component method, even the are rendered on different element

Comment: Thanks for the extended reply. In the meantime, I managed to make my `Modal` based on portals, and now it's components all the way down, e.g.

```<DoSomethingButton><Modal><DoSomethingForm/></Modal></DoSomethingButton>```